# Looking for a source about Avraham compared to Noah

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, abraham, noach-noah-the-man

I'm having some trouble tracking down a source I saw earlier that I'd like to review.

Around Beresheit 18:18 when Hashem is deciding whether or not to tell Avraham about the impending destruction of Sodom ( וַֽיהֹוָ֖ה אָמָ֑ר הַֽמְכַסֶּ֤ה אֲנִי֙ מֵֽאַבְרָהָ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֖ר אֲנִ֥י עֹשֶֽׂה׃) one of the commentators contrasts how Hashem treats Avraham - i.e. he confides in him and gives him a chance to plead for Sodom, vs. how Hashem treats Noach where Hashem just tells Noach that the world will be destroyed.  The commentator also mentions how Moshe is also allowed to plead for Bnei Yisrael when Hashem was going to destroy us.

Does anyone happen to recognize who made this observation, and where he made it?

Comment: It could be from the Talmud. I think it is a possible source. The Talmud addresses some criticism regarding Noah. Noah walked with G-d for Noah has perfect faith. That was it. Abraham, on the other hand walked before G-d, leading the way. In other words, Moshe and Abraham questioned the divine decree, the verdict to destroy Sodom and Israel where Noah took the threat with blind faith and saved himself. Israel means to struggle with G-d. We should question everything, even G-d, as the patriarchs have done and not rely on G-d or blind faith. A Midrash says even a fool can be a righteous fool.

Comment: That could be a good place to look, do you happen to know where?  Masechet? Daf?

Comment: Yes. Rabbi Judah in the Midrash Genesis Rabbah questioned Noah’s ‘righteous.’ He said in the Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 108a, regarding Noah, that “In a street of totally blind people, a one-eyed man is called clear-sighted, and an infant a scholar.”

Comment: Rabbi Nehemiah said that while Noah in Genesis 6:9 “walked with G-d,” Abraham in 17:1 walks “before Me [G-d].” which means that Noah had to rely on G-d while Avraham led the way. Some went as far as to say that Noah was only righteous in his generation (and would not be in another) simply because he did not warn anyone about the coming flood. Indeed the Mishnah, Pirke Avot 2:6 says that: “An individual who acts without reason can still be a righteous fool.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial source, from זוהר ח"א סז ע"ב comparing Noah negatively with Moshe, who prayed for his generation:

> תא חזי מה בין משה לשאר בני עלמא. בשעתא דאמר לה קודשא בריך הוא למשה
>   'ועתה הניחה לי' וגו' 'ואעשה אותך לגוי גדול' וגו', מיד אמר משה: וכי
>   אשבוק דינהון דישראל בגיני? השתא יימרון כל אינון בני עלמא דאנא קטלית
>   לון לישראל, כמה דעבד נח. דכיוון דאמר ליה קודש אבריך הוא דישזיב ליה
>   בתיבותא, דכתיב 'ואני הנני מביא את המבול מים' וגו', וכתיב 'ומחיתי את כל
>   היקום אשר עשיתי מעל פני האדמה ואני הנני מקים את בריתי וגו' ובאת אל
>   התבה', כיוון דאמר ליה דישתזיב הוא ובנוי, לא בעא רחמין על עלמא
>   ואתאבידו. ובגין כך אקרון מי המבול על שמיה כמה דאת אמר 'כי מי נח זאת לי
>   אשר נשבעתי מעבור מי נח'.

(I found it [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/25964#13a).)

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thanks

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Rashbi in your quotation also compares Avraham negatively to Moshe Rabbeinu. The Zohar explains that only Moshe actually prayed for his generation until G-d reversed His decree. It also says that G-d told Noach of the impending flood hoping that Noach would pray for his generation like Moshe ultimately did. Instead, Noach merely followed G-d's instructions to build the ark. Rashbi emphasizes that Noach was absolutely righteous but failed to pray for his generation.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Judah in the Midrash Genesis Rabbah questioned Noah’s ‘righteous.’ He said in the Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 108a, regarding Noah, that “In a street of totally blind people, a one-eyed man is called clear-sighted, and an infant a scholar.”

Rabbi Nehemiah said that while Noah in Genesis 6:9 “walked with G-d,” Abraham in 17:1 walks “before Me [G-d].” which means that Noah had to rely on G-d while Avraham led the way. Some went as far as to say that Noah was only righteous in his generation (and would not be in another) simply because he did not warn anyone about the coming flood. Indeed the Mishnah, Pirke Avot 2:6 says that: “An individual who acts without reason can still be a righteous fool.”

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @DonielF The question was "Looking for a source about Avraham compared to Noah" I can't see how this does not answer the question.

Comment: Wasn’t just about comparing Avraham to Noach, but comparing Avraham arguing with Hashem on others’ behalf to Noach’s silent acquiescence. You definitely mention that Noach was quiet, but you don’t quote a source that explicitly contrasts specifically these two points.

Comment: I quoted the Talmud, Sanhedrin 108a and the Mishnah, Pirke Avot 2:6.

Comment: Which mention nothing about Avraham.

Comment: Rabbi Nehemiah Compared Abraham to Noah.

Comment: Abraham and Moshe questioned the verdict with G-d while Noah was silent. I think there is a Midrash somewhere which says that Noah built the ark for 100 years, all the long warning the people about the flood and yet they wouldn’t listen. Not sure where exactly this comes from. Nevertheless I deem it inventive to redeem Noah’s character when the Torah itself is silent upon the matter. Much like how the Talmud claims Moshe commanded the sun to stand still like Joshua. Ralbag thinks it invented since the Torah would have not gone silent upon the matter.

Comment: I agree that R’ Nechemiah compared Avraham to Noach, but not in the specific manner OP was asking about.

Comment: The OP was asking, to my understanding, why did Abraham/Moshe question the verdict when Noah failed to do so. The quote Abraham walking before G0d (leading the way) and Noah walking with G-d (relying on one's faith) answers because it expresses the opinion that where Noah relied on the fact that whatever G-d did was good, Abraham questioned the morality. Of course, G-d does only good. Rambam makes this clear. The point is to question, even G-d.

Comment: The OP was not asking for why. The OP was asking for a source for someone who notes the discrepancy. “Does anyone happen to recognize who made this observation and where he made it?”

Comment: Rabbi Nechemiah and Rabbi Yehuda. They are the source and the ones who made such a claim.

Comment: No he doesn’t! He compares Avraham and Noach, but he doesn’t compare Avraham’s pleading with Noach’s not doing so.

Comment: Let's try this again. Rabbi Nehemiah said that while Noah in Genesis 6:9 “walked with G-d,” Abraham in 17:1 walks “before Me [G-d].” which means that Noah had to rely on G-d while Avraham led the way. what does this mean? It means that where Noah was silent and relied on faith, Abraham quested the divine decree.

Comment: All they say is that one walked “with” while the other walked “before.” You’re sticking into them that that’s what they mean. I don’t disagree that that may be a valid interpretation, but surely you admit they don’t say those particular words.

Comment: You are right if you read the plain meaning of the words. Interpretation suggest that they mean something else. It is a matter of interpretation then. A derash.

Comment: Certainly. But then you’re the source of the OP’s statement, not the Gemara.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's coming from [Bereshit Rabbah 49:2 on Bereshit 18:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Bereishit_Rabbah.49.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en), which says:

> **אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בְּרַבִּי סִימוֹן** לְמֶלֶךְ שֶׁהָיוּ לוֹ שְׁלשָׁה אוֹהֲבִים וְלֹא הָיָה עוֹשֶׂה דָּבָר חוּץ מִדַּעְתָּן, פַּעַם אַחַת בִּקֵּשׁ הַמֶּלֶךְ לַעֲשׂוֹת דָּבָר חוּץ מִדַּעְתָּן, נָטַל אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹן וּטְרָדוֹ וְהוֹצִיאוֹ חוּץ לַפָּלָטִין, שֵׁנִי חֲבָשׁוֹ בְּבֵית הָאֲסוּרִים, וְנָתַן סְפָרְגִים שֶׁלּוֹ עָלָיו, **שְׁלִישִׁי שֶׁהָיָה חָבִיב לוֹ יוֹתֵר מִדַּאי אָמַר אֵינִי עוֹשֶׂה דָּבָר חוּץ מִדַּעְתּוֹ.** כָּךְ, אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן (בראשית ג, כד): וַיְגָרֶשׁ אֶת הָאָדָם. נֹחַ (בראשית ז, טז): וַיִּסְגֹּר ה' בַּעֲדוֹ. **אַבְרָהָם שֶׁהָיָה חָבִיב עָלָיו יוֹתֵר מִדַּאי, אָמַר מָה אֲנִי עוֹשֶׂה דָּבָר חוּץ מִדַּעְתּוֹ**.

It was Rabbi Yehuda, son of Rabbi Simon who made the observation.

This quote from the midrash explains in connection with G-d's questioning the idea of concealing the judgement against Sodom from Avraham, that G-d had a special love (that he was cherished *more than appropriate*) for Avraham above and beyond others (*Adam and Noach are listed as examples of those not loved like Avraham. Thus, Adam was separated and Noach was imprisoned at the time of judgement.*). And that because of that special type of love, G-d sought Avraham's opinion in things that G-d would do to the world.

Regarding your association of Moshe Rabbeinu to this special type of merit connected with Avraham, the beginning of the linked midrash explains how this merit from Avraham was passed along to the 70 individuals who descended to Egypt, who ultimately became the 70 Elders who transmitted the teachings of Avraham to Moshe, who explained the Torah in 70 languages.

Comment: Only the part about Avraham is quoted here, not the comparison to Noach.

Comment: The quote dealing with Noach is unbolded. I also didn’t quote the whole section because it wasn’t dealing with the main aspect of the OPs question. But it’s all there. Follow the link.

Comment: Surely you’ve been around long enough to know that all relevant information should be in the post itself rather than in a link?

Comment: @DonielF The question is only about where is the source for the comparison between Avraham & Noach where G-d wants to reveal the destruction of Sodom to get Avraham’s reaction & who said it & how this differs with Noach. That exact event & comparison is in my quote. I also answer who said it. The other answers do not do this. Also, in terms of earliest sources, Bereshit Rabbah is the earliest we have. Your comments are simply wrong & the voting here indicates people aren’t reading the answers.

Comment: Surely the burden is on the author to make his post as clear as possible? I’ve read this answer several times now and still can’t figure which part addresses the comparison between Noach and Avraham. (Also, Zohar isn’t earlier than Bereishis Rabbah? Both are Tannaic-based.)

Comment: @DonielF So what you are really saying is that you do not understand the Hebrew of the Midrash Rabbah quote. If you want me to do a translation on-the-fly, just say so. But the OP didn't ask for it and frankly, the Aramaic Zohar quotation you understand but not the Hebrew of the Midrash?! Regarding origin of Midrash Rabbah, it's generally considered to be 4th century CE. Zohar, although attributed to Rashbi (some dispute this), was completely unknown until the newly discovered manuscript was publicized by Rabbi Moshe de Leon 13th century CE. Think about this in terms of Dead Sea scrolls.

Comment: I can read the Hebrew just fine. I see the part very clearly which says that He confided in Avraham and not Noach, but I don’t see the part where Avraham pleads and Noach doesn’t. (Surely the Midrash agrees that Noach knew the Mabul was happening ahead of time?) Also, yes, your answer can be improved for those on this site who can’t read the Hebrew.

Comment: @DonielF It's also worth pointing out that the OP is specifically asking about the comparison between Avraham and Noach. The Moshe comment is a side note. The Zohar quote doesn't address Avraham at all. Nor does the Zohar quote, as presented, mention who is making the statement. (Something specifically asked for in the question.) Your critique here, while welcome, is ridiculous & irrelevant. But you are entitled to your opinion.